# Page down/up when clicking in the VSCode scrollbar

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a setting to change the click behavior in the scrollbar to page up/down instead of jumping to the location in the file? This is the usual scrollbar behavior in almost every other applications except maybe unix applications.
A suggestion could be:

- Left click: page up/down
- Right click: jump to location

Comment: The previously mentioned feature request was closed for lack of upvotes. Another one exists which is still open and has more votes, https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/43564.

Answer (score 5):

There is a setting for this now:

`Editor: Scroll by Page`

> Controls whether clicks scrolls by page or
> jumps to click position.

With that setting enabled, the editor will scroll by one viewport page when clicking anywhere above or below the scrollThumb.  With it not enabled (the default) it will scroll to the position in the scroll track where you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

This behavior does not currently exist. I suggest opening a feature request on [github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new).

Comment: Someone did open a feature request, but it appears to need more upvotes: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/87273

Answer (score 0):

If, like me, you've been brought to this page despite putting "Visual Studio" into your web search, you can modify this behaviour in the full blown Visual Studio as follows:

- Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars
- Under "Behavior", toggle between `bar mode` and `map mode`

More information can be found by reading the [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-track-your-code-by-customizing-the-scrollbar?view=vs-2022) for this feature.